# Python Celery asynchronous tasks are not executed

Tags: python, celery

I am learning to use Celery to create asynchronous tasks in python

this is my code

```py
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery("hello", backend="rpc://", broker="amqp://guest@localhost//")


@app.task
def hello():
    time.sleep(5)
    with open("./test.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        fp.write("ok")

    return "hello world"
```

Celery startup information

```sh
> celery -A main worker -l INFO
 
 -------------- celery@ajanuw v5.2.1 (dawn-chorus)    
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0 2021-12-07 08:56:00
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         hello:0x1c616583040   
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . main.hello

[2021-12-07 08:56:00,970: INFO/MainProcess] Connected 
to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2021-12-07 08:56:01,013: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-12-07 08:56:01,370: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 2000 calling self.run()



[2021-12-07 08:56:14,018: INFO/MainProcess] Task main.hello[010042fd-4839-
received
```

Call the hello function

```py
>>> from main import *

>>> hello.delay()
<AsyncResult: 010042fd-4839-46c0-8602-cf192f6b50b9>
```

I don't know what went wrong, the file has not been created

Version Information

```
> python -V
Python 3.10.0

celery==5.2.1

rabbitmq:3.9.11-management
```

[image]

Comment: What is the result of your AsyncResult's `.state` and `.get()`?

Comment: My guess is what is the current dir when its trying to open the file? use a full path

Comment: @fooiey  I just checked the state is always ‘PENDING’ and get can’t get the value

Comment: @PeterMoore I don’t know if it’s a path problem, but when I call `hello()` synchronously, the file will be created, but the file is not created when I call `hello.delay()` asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how the test is on windows, it will not succeed, so I installed Python 3.8.10 on wsl ubuntu to test and found that the asynchronous task can be executed correctly. I don’t know why it doesn’t work on windows.